# Do imports go in main function or if stsatement?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

So where should I put import statements which are only used by main function, at the top of it's body or `if __name__ == "__main__":` ?

Comment: The presence of an `if __name__` block implies that the script might be imported. If it's imported, you probably need the imports to be run so that the code will work.

Comment: @khelwood They are only used in main function.

Comment: Then you could just import them in the main function, if the rationale is that you don't want the extra work of importing them when your script is imported. But it's probably unnecessary optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Import statements appear at the top of a Python file, beneath any comments that may exist. This is because importing modules or packages at the top of a file makes the structure of your code clearer.

Full explanation:
[How to Use the Python import Statement](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-import/)